# ADF json expression formatting

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've been doing this for about 6 hours now, so I'm turning to the crowd. 
I am using ADF to move data from and API to a DB. I'm using the REST copy data activity and I need to properly format a json for the body param with two pipeline parameters and an item from a for loop. My json needs to be formatted as such:

```
"key" : ["value"]
```

I'm have difficulty understanding how to format the json body. I believe I need to start the whole body using the json expression:

```
@json('{"foo":"bar"}')
```

But I am unable to get the pipeline parameters to be properly expressed in the json. This is makes the most sense as far as I understand it and it simply returns what you see when I peek in the input window.

```
@json('{"foo":["activity('bar').output.value]"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"key":["@{activity('bar').output.value}"]
```

Works, but I still believe I should just be able to pass an array!